# Winforms TabControl alignment problems

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

When I set TabControl alignment to `Left` or `Right` it leaves this huge space between tab buttons and tab page area. How to get rid of this useless space?

`TabControl.Appearance` is set to `Buttons` because if it is set to `Normal` the text on buttons disappear.

[image: tabcontrol]

UPDATE:
When i set `TabControl.Alignment` to `Bottom` and `TabControl.Appearance` to `Normal` buttons look inverted (orange line should be below)
[image: tab control]

When i set `TabControl.Alignment` to `Bottom` and `TabControl.Appearance` to `Buttons`, There is no area on `TabPage` to place controls
[image]

Comment: Interesting. I just tried this in C# 2010 Express, and I see the behavior you're showing here. However, when I change `Appearance` to `Normal`, everything looks normal and the text is still visible. When in `Normal` mode, do you EVER see the text (either at design-time or at run-time)?

Comment: No, no text in Normal mode when left or right aligned. This is the reason i changed mode

Comment: Side-aligned tabs are hideous and the text is extremely difficult to read. Why are you doing this? Keep them at the top or the bottom where they go. Your life will be so much simpler if you follow the standard conventions.

Comment: Ok, i have another problem with them on bottom. see the images

Comment: @Code Gray, The thing is that i don't like them on top or left in my scenario. They should be either bottom or right aligned

Comment: It seems to me I have the same problem with the Bottom alignment. I submitted a bug report to Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/710836/tabcontrol-windows-form-application-does-not-render-properly-when-alignment-is-tabalignment-bottom

Comment: This is still a bug in Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 10 (1809).  TabControl.Alignment == Right, Appearance == Normal works. However if Appearance == FlatButtons, causes TabPages to be forced to half width.

Answer (score 5):

This is a well-known problem with the XP visual style implementation for the native tab control, only tabs aligned to the top render properly.  This bug hasn't been addressed until Windows 7.  The workaround is to selectively turn off the style.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto your form and change the Alignment property to your liking.  It isn't going to look prettier than that.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class FixedTabControl : TabControl {

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "", "");
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }

    [DllImportAttribute("uxtheme.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appname, string idlist);
}
```

Comment: Should I consider it a 'Feature'?

Comment: Being able to work around the problem with a couple of lines of code?  Yes, that's a quite a feature.  Winforms always does that well.  If you mean "doesn't that look kinda odd, should I call it a feature" then, no, nobody has ever seen vertical tabs with a visual style.  They look normal.

Comment: Thank you that works. If you are trying to fix a form that already has a TabControl, then edit the Designer.cs file and search and replace System.Windows.Forms.TabControl with FixedTabControl.

Comment: @HansPassant "This is a well-known problem", do you know whether the bug was ever submitted to Microsoft?

Comment: I'm 100% sure they know about this.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, anyway I submitted a bug report to Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/710836/tabcontrol-windows-form-application-does-not-render-properly-when-alignment-is-tabalignment-bottom#details

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft documentation Remarks related to this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.alignment?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

> When the Alignment property is set to Left or Right, the Multiline
>   property is automatically set to true.
>
> When you set the Appearance property to FlatButtons, it only appears
>   as such when the Alignment property is set to Top. Otherwise, the
>   Appearance property displays as if set to the Buttons value.
>
> When you set the Appearance property to Buttons, you must also set the
>   Alignment property to Top so that the buttons display correctly.
>
> Note
>
> When you set the Appearance property to Buttons, you must also set the
>   Alignment property to Top so that the tab page contents display
>   correctly. Additionally, when visual styles are enabled, and the
>   Alignment property is set to a value other than Top, the tab contents
>   may not render correctly.