# TabControl and borders visual glitch

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have these visual glitches on every `tabControls` when I am changing its `tabPages` `BackColor` and the `BackColor` of the form, as illustrated on the following images:

- At the top of the `tabPage`, there is an interior one-pixel white border.
- At the left of the `tabPage`, there is an interior three-pixels white border.
- At the bottom of the `tabPage`, there is an interior one-pixel white border and an exterior two-pixels white border.
- At the right of the `tabPage`, there is an interior one-pixel white border and an exterior two-pixels white border.

[image: Top and left borders]
[image: Bottom borders]
[image: Top and right borders]

Is there a way I can get rid of those white borders?

Comment: What happens if you set the backcolor for the parent(tabcontrol)?

Comment: @Rob: Unfortunately, a `tabControl` has no BackColor property.

Comment: Oke, you could try to set the margin of the tabpage using css.. 
margin:-1px -3px -3px -3px; It causes the field to be a little bit bigger and override the whitespace

Comment: you have to do it by setting DrawMode to Owner and then paint the tabcontrol

Comment: @Rob: I tried changing the padding and margin of the `tabPage` and the `tabControl`, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @rapsalands: I'd rather not go on this way, because I'd have to completely redraw the tabs, and that doesn't seem a piece of cake to get the tabs just as they appear when `DrawMode` is set at `Normal`.

Comment: Something else must be going on.  I can't reproduce that behavior.

Comment: @LarsTech: You don't have any white borders? I just created a new winform application, added a `tabControl` on `Form1`, changed the `BackColor` of `tabPage1` and the `BackColor` of `Form1` and I clearly have all the white borders I have described: http://i.imgur.com/5ZhVH.png

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.  My fault.  I understood "glitch" to mean it was drawing something wrong.  That's just the TabControl doing it's thing with VisualStyles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the border padding on container controls in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968267/how-can-i-remove-the-border-padding-on-container-controls-in-winforms)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's my attempted hack.  I used a `NativeWindow` to draw over the `TabControl` to fill in those "white" spaces.  I won't claim it's perfect:

```
public class TabPadding : NativeWindow {
  private const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;

  private TabControl tabControl;

  public TabPadding(TabControl tc) {
    tabControl = tc;
    tabControl.Selected += new TabControlEventHandler(tabControl_Selected);
    AssignHandle(tc.Handle);
  }

  void tabControl_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) {
    tabControl.Invalidate();
  }

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT) {
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(m.HWnd)) {

        //Replace the outside white borders:
        if (tabControl.Parent != null) {
          g.SetClip(new Rectangle(0, 0, tabControl.Width - 2, tabControl.Height - 1), CombineMode.Exclude);
          using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(tabControl.Parent.BackColor))
          g.FillRectangle(sb, new Rectangle(0, 
                                            tabControl.ItemSize.Height + 2,
                                            tabControl.Width,
                                            tabControl.Height - (tabControl.ItemSize.Height + 2)));
        }

        //Replace the inside white borders:
        if (tabControl.SelectedTab != null) {
          g.ResetClip();
          Rectangle r = tabControl.SelectedTab.Bounds;
          g.SetClip(r, CombineMode.Exclude);
          using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(tabControl.SelectedTab.BackColor))
            g.FillRectangle(sb, new Rectangle(r.Left - 3,
                                              r.Top - 1,
                                              r.Width + 4,
                                              r.Height + 3));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And to hook it up:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  var tab = new TabPadding(tabControl1);
}
```

My end result:

[image]

Comment: Looks really smooth. For now, I find it perfect. I will keep you up to date if I find some glitch. Thanks a lot, amazing work!

Comment: Wow, thank you for that. Thank you very much! Does exactly what one would expect the TabControl to do (and once again "Microsoft, why?!")

Comment: I couldn't get this solution to work for me. I copied the code exactly and created a new TabPadding with my existing tabControl - it did nothing.

Comment: @stuzor You would have to show me your code in order for me to help you.

Comment: It's perfect, bravo!

Comment: In addition to your answer, to remove all borders
`using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(tabControl.SelectedTab.BackColor))
                                g.FillRectangle(sb, new Rectangle(r.Left - 4, r.Top - 1, r.Width + 6, r.Height + 7));`
to leave just a small top line
`r.Top - 2,`

Answer (score 8):

you can inherit from control

```
public class TabControlEx : TabControl
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x1300 + 40)
        {
            RECT rc = (RECT)m.GetLParam(typeof(RECT));
            rc.Left -= 0;
            rc.Right += 3;
            rc.Top -= 0;
            rc.Bottom += 3;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, true);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
internal struct RECT { public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom; }
```

Comment: This is the only solution on this page that works for me, however I had to adjust Left to -= 4, Right to += 2, and Top to -= 2. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the exact numbers differ across platforms. This works well "on my machine" but I need different numbers yet again.

Comment: @DrewNoakes same, i got to use 7 on left right and bottom, but top doesn't work instead of removing the lines it removes the tabheaders :|

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem and never found a good simple solution.  That's when I thought about simply adjusting the control's clipping region.  This seemed to work just fine with no noticeable side-effects.  The 2 extra white pixels on the right side and the one extra white pixel at the bottom are no longer visible.

```
class TabControlEx : TabControl
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0005) // WM_SIZE
        {
            int Width = unchecked((short)m.LParam);
            int Height = unchecked((short)((uint)m.LParam >> 16));

            // Remove the annoying white pixels on the outside of the tab control
            // by adjusting the control's clipping region to exclude the 2 pixels
            // on the right and one pixel on the bottom.
            Region = new Region(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 2, Height - 1));
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it's fixing overdraw, where contents spill outside. I think the original question is about tab controls that have padding you can't simply remove in the designer.

Comment: Yes, re-reading the original question after all this time it does appear to be a different scenario.  I was using a tab control with default colours on a form with a custom background.  The Tab control was drawing white borders on two sides and this code eliminates that.