# Get rid of TabControl Border

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, i want to get rid of the ugly Border of the TabControl. I tried using this Code, but it did not Work

```cs
class MultiPagePanel : Panel
{
  private int _currentPageIndex;
  public int CurrentPageIndex
  {
    get { return _currentPageIndex; }
    set
    {
      if (value >= 0 && value < Controls.Count)
      {
        Controls[value].BringToFront();
        _currentPageIndex = value;
      }
    }
  }

  public void AddPage(Control page)
  {
    Controls.Add(page);
    page.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  }
}
```

So what can i do against the Borders on the TabControl?

Comment: [TCM_ADJUSTRECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tcm-adjustrect) message.

Comment: Can I suggest starting with a search on SO first? Does this answer your question? [TabControl and borders visual glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768555/tabcontrol-and-borders-visual-glitch)

Comment: @LucMorin I seached and tried every code i found

Comment: What TabControl? I see no one here. Maybe a screenshot of what you are doing could help.