# How to remove the spacing between a tab control and a panel control?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get rid off the white spacing between both panels:

[image: delete the white border]

Comment: Please indicate clearly in your screenshot, with a circle or a mark, what is the "white" space you want to remove

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7768555/14171304

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the Panel in the designer, small squares will appear in the borders of the panel. Then, drag the border until it is overlapping with the other panel to remove the space between them:

[image]