# How to remove gaps on TabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

Could somebody know how to avoid left and right gaps (each about 5-10 px) between a page on TabControl and TabControl itself. I tried everything. All margins and padings are zero.

Comment: nobody knows or something wrong in question ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the border padding on container controls in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968267/how-can-i-remove-the-border-padding-on-container-controls-in-winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a comment left in the source code for TabPage by an exasperated Microsoft programmer:

```
    //HACK: to ensure that the tabpage draws correctly (the border will get clipped and
    // and gradient fill will match correctly with the tabcontrol).  Unfortunately, there is no good way to determine
    // the padding used on the tabpage.
    // I would like to use the following below, but GetMargins is busted in the theming API:
    //VisualStyleRenderer visualStyleRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Tab.Pane.Normal);
    //Padding themePadding = visualStyleRenderer.GetMargins(e.Graphics, MarginProperty.ContentMargins);
```

Credit to: Hans Passant :-)

Comment: ThanYou, Vijay. I paid my VS a lot of money, and it's not fair that i can't do so minor thing. Let's say - solved.