# Removing the padding around a Tab control in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove the border padding on container controls in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968267/how-can-i-remove-the-border-padding-on-container-controls-in-winforms)

I've developed a Winforms application in Visual studio 2008. On the main form I have a **Tab control**. Now I am trying to use a **background image** to the tab page. The problem that I am running into is that the tab control seems to have a thick border around it. Also the tab control does not cover the entire form leaving a line of space over the top between the form and tab page. (*I have the tab pages alignment set at bottom*). So a border around the tab control and line of space at the top making my page look ugly. I tried to give the same image as the background to form, but the tab control padding playing the spoilsport.

Any ideas to make my design better would be appreciated.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Screenshots would help **a lot**.

Comment: inherit the control and draw it the way you want it to look. This is how people are ablet to have buttons that are not square and/or rectangle.  I don't understand the complaint.  The simple solution is to design your own control that doesn't have this border.

Comment: ooh!! How you do that? A little more detail please

Comment: @Ramhound a bit OTT if you are simply looking to have a background image.

Comment: @Cdeez - Inherit the control, then write code that overrides how the control is gone, there are tons of examples on the internet.

Comment: @James - It might be but clearly the tab control won't work in this case.

Comment: @Ramhound Agreed, I do think some custom drawing might actually be in order to fix this scenario - see [TabControl and borders visual glitch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768555/tabcontrol-and-borders-visual-glitch)

Comment: Wow, that's ugly. What was wrong with the standard background? You know, the one where you can actually read the text. And the one you can change if you don't like the color blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the majority of comments made here. The standard TabControl is drawn very poorly on Microsoft's Part...even in Windows Vista / 7 it doesn't look great! You would be better to write your own custom implementation by inheriting the TabControl and then drawing the additional stuff you want.

You might consider using this as a template for your new control. You just need to add some cool design / drawing work to the OnPaint and OnPaintBackground methods.

```
namespace CustomControls
{
    #region USING

    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    #endregion

    public class CustomTabControl : TabControl
    {
        #region VARIABLES

        private int hotTrackTab = -1;

        #endregion

        #region INSTANCE CONSTRUCTORS

        public CustomTabControl() : base()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion

        #region INSTANCE METHODS

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

            this.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        }

        private int GetTabUnderCursor()
        {
            Point cursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            for (int index = 0; index < this.TabPages.Count; index++)
            {
                if (this.GetTabRect(index).Contains(cursor))
                {
                    return index;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        private void UpdateHotTrack()
        {
            int hot = GetTabUnderCursor();
            if (hot != this.hotTrackTab)
            {
                if (this.hotTrackTab != -1)
                {
                    this.Invalidate(this.GetTabRect(this.hotTrackTab));
                }
                this.hotTrackTab = hot;
                if (this.hotTrackTab != -1)
                {
                    this.Invalidate(this.GetTabRect(this.hotTrackTab));
                }
                this.Update();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region OVERRIDE METHODS

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            this.UpdateHotTrack();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
            this.UpdateHotTrack();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            this.UpdateHotTrack();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            switch (this.Alignment)
            {
                case TabAlignment.Bottom:
                case TabAlignment.Left:
                case TabAlignment.Right:
                case TabAlignment.Top:
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that the code above draw an absolutely blank TabControl that only displays the DisplayRectangle. Everything else including the tabs you will need to do yourself!

Additionally, to draw backgrounds for individual TabPages, you may need to override and custom implement TabPage as well, however you might be able to achieve the result you are looking for with just a custom tab control.

Check this out
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42046/Customized-TabControl-by-Repainting-Microsoft-s-Pa

IMHO This is better...
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38014/KRBTabControl

IMHO this is better still...
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition

also look on VB Forums...I know I've seem some awesome custom tab controls on there!