# WinForms tabpage not repainting on form resize

Tags: .net, winforms, resize, tabcontrol, paint

Is there a reason why a .NET WinForms `TabPage` doesn't fully repaint its background when I resize the Form? It should be completely white (in Windows 7), but a portion remains gray (`SystemColors.Control`, most likely). Whenever I hit the maximize button, currently visible `TabPage` background doesn't get redrawn. Also, if I resize it, I need to move the form past the screen boundaries in order for it to get painted.

The same thing happens if I minimize and then restore the form. In that case the `TabPage` background remains grey. Child controls are rendered properly (labels, for example, keep their white backgrounds).

I am using Windows 7 32-bit, .NET 3.5. Tab control was added using the Visual Studio designer, and contains a couple of labels and two text boxes. I haven't changed any native style flags related to paint messages.

**[Edit]**

I have created a test project, source is [uploaded here](http://pastebin.com/LJNE3c20).

This is how the window looks initially:

[image: Form initial state]

This is how the window looks after I minimize it and then restore it:

[image: Minimized, then restored]

Note the change in `TabPage` background color.

Comment: Have you set any `Dock` or `Anchor` property? set `Dock` to fill and see if problem exist. If this is not a case, a screenshot would be a better mean of understanding your problem.

Comment: @Saeid87: `Anchor` is set to `All`. I have uploaded two screenshots of the form, showing what happens if I minimize and then restore the window. I can post the code, but there is nothing to it: just an anchored `TabControl` containing a `Label` and a `TextBox`, I just made this test project inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok, I've added the [source code](http://pastebin.com/LJNE3c20) also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove the border padding on container controls in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968267/how-can-i-remove-the-border-padding-on-container-controls-in-winforms)

Comment: @Hans: thanks, these are some very insightful answers. Does this mean setting the background to a fixed color [like Saeid wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12339018/1488067) is ok? Or I really need to PInvoke `uxtheme.dll`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I recon your problem can be solved by doing the folowing steps:

For the `tabPage` set `UseVisualStyleBackColor` to `False` and just set its `BackColor` to the color you  want, in this case `White`

Also instead of setting anchor to all sides, just set `Dock` to `Fill`. 
Generally avoid setting size for labels, try only anchors for them.

Comment: +1 That fixed it. Although now I need to handle Windows XP separately, because TabControl doesn't have a white background in that OS. And users with visual styles (themes) turned off will also expect a different color. I would be much happier if I didn't need to do this manually. Regarding the `Dock` vs `Anchor`, using `Dock` by itself didn't solve my problem, and `Dock` is only useful if you have a single control to place, and you don't care about losing all margins. `Dock` is just a simplified special case of `Anchor` IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this by adding a call to tabControl.Refresh() inside the tabControl's ClientSizeChanged method. Note that that's for the overall Tab Control and not each individual Tab Page.

Answer (score 2):

This visual styles bug has been fixed in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Do you have any sources on that?

Comment: Afraid not, only personal experience with other projects. You'll find that if you target the sample application you provided to .NET 4 the issue goes away.  The visual styles renderer, as well as the painting logic in the tabpage, has always been a little *special*.